# labelling vertices of a polyhedron with letters

Tags: education, solid-geometry

Maybe a stupid question, but I have not met yet a clear answer. Say that the label of a cube is ABCDEFGH: does it mean that there are faces ABCD and EFGH so that E, F, G and H are respectively the images of A, B, C and D under a translation, or that ABCDEFGH(A) defines an Hamiltonian path on the cube ? It seems to me that the first is the "right" answer, but the second seems quite logical too, and I don't know where to find some historic discussion on it (if this exists). Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Have you seen a person use that notation before?  Have you seen any diagrams used by that person?  I would personally never have used that notation in the first place, for exactly the reason you are asking this question.  Instead, I would have either made it clear from a graphic, or have used specific points in space to describe the vertices, such as letting my cube "be $\{0,1\}^3$" which has the points $(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),\dots,(1,1,1)$ at which point it is obvious which of the points lie on the same face.

Comment: I have seen many trainee primary schoolteacher use different notations, and this is not a college level question

Comment: And many primary schoolteachers don't recognize the necessity for consistent unambiguous notation or why it might be important how to communicate which of the vertices share a face.  If it matters, use whatever interpretation of the notation you want and explain your interpretation of the notation when you use it.  That an ambiguous notation exists in the world should be a non-issue so long as if and when you happen to use that notation you are clear about its meaning.